# Can I connect my PC to a 2nd router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I'm no professional in this and am just trying to seek advice.

I recently bought a new router(`Nokia beacon 1` wi-fi mesh) but it apparently only has 1 LAN port and so
-I can only connect either my ethernet(It's  blue) cable from PC to router
-or another white ethernet cable from my TV set-up box to the router

---

Is this a possible solution?

1)Buy another `Nokia beacon 1`

2)Add it to the network, apparently, there's an app that I can just download and click "Add to Network"

3)Connect my PC's cable to the 2nd router's LAN port. Connect set-up box's cable to 1st router's LAN port

Comment: There's another possible (and "correct") solution that is better than what you proposed: add an (Ethernet) switch to your LAN.  An unmanaged switch should also cost less than a router.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with all these terms but a Google search showed me a picture of multiple LAN ports. Am I right to assume, a switch is just house for multiple Ethernet cables and then you connect the switch to the router?

Comment: Yes, but it is smart, and doesn't send packets everywhere.  Get a switch with enough ports (e.g. 5, 8, 16) to connect the router and each network device (e.g. desktop, laptop, smart TV, game console, printer, another switch, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Please do read up on some networking basics. Google "introduction to networking" or something similar. You'll need the background, and the Q&A on this site is not suitable to give a complete background.

A [switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch) is a networking device that connects multiple computers "passively". In the simplest variant, packets that go into one port ("housing for an internet cable") will go out through all other ports.

Think of it as some kind of "power strip" for networking, but there's no dedicated cable where the power goes "in".

So yes,

> a switch is just house for multiple Ethernet cables and then you connect the switch to the router?

You connect the switch to the router and to all your computing devices, and then the router will tell all computing devices that they are in your home network (the protocol for that is called DHCP). Then the computing devices can connect to the internet through the switch and the router, and connect to each other through the switch.